# How can I insert a commit before rebasing?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-commit

I have a history that looks a little like this right now:

```
                  origin/master
                        |
A --- B --- C --- D --- E
                   \
                     -- F
                        |
                     master
```

I want to rebase my changes (commit F) after E, but there are some fairly major issues in commit E I would like to correct first. Basically, this is what I want to be able to get to:

```
                  origin/master
                        |
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- G
                   \
                     -- F
                        |
                     master
```

I *then* want to rebase F on at the end, for a final, simple result:

```
                              origin/master
                                    |
A --- B --- C --- D --- E --- G --- F
```

How can I "put aside" commit F while I work on the main trunk, then rebase it on later? I would assume it would involve `git branch`, but I don't know enough git to know the sequence of commands to issue. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a branch pointing to your `F` commit:

```
git branch tmp
```

Remove `F` commit from `master` branch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

Make your fixes and commit them:

```
git commit
```

Add `F` commit on top of current `master` branch (this can result in conflicts, so resolve them):

```
git cherry-pick tmp
```

Remove temporary branch:

```
git branch -d tmp
```

So you don't really need `git rebase` here, it's for more complex things or at least not for working with one commit.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a separate branch for F, if not - I missed that and you should create it. 
I would recommend you not to work on master with commit  G, but also have a separate branch for it as well 
Please create a separate branch for it. 
1. Then, try to rebase the branch that contains f against that branch (perhaps using git rebase --onto, 
although I think there is another way to do that) 
Another way to do this, is to perform git format-patch origin/master at the branch that contains F, and then apply this patch on the branch that contains G. 
You might of course run into conflicts. 
Based on my experience - option 1 is better , for some reason git apply and git am are more "fragile" (sorry for the bad term) than performing rebasing against another branch.